# String size is equal to number of characters

Tags: c, arrays, string, printf

I was making a basic program of strings and did this. There is a string in this way:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char str[7]="network";
    printf("%s",str);
    return 0;
}
```

It prints `network`.In my view, it should not print network. Some garbage value should be printed because `'\0'` does not end this character array. So how it got printed? There were no warning or errors too.

Comment: You got lucky and `'\0'` provided by `"network"` wasn't overwritten by anything else when you were printing `str`.

Comment: I wouldn't be so quick to accept an answser. None of the answers actually address your question.

Comment: in c++ its necessary that string array is one bigger than total number of characters  but in c this is not the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because

```
char str[7]="network";
```

is the same as

```
char str[7]={'n','e','t','w','o','r','k'};
```

`str` is a valid `char` array, but not a string, because it's no null-terminated. So it's undefined behavior to use `%s` to print it.

Reference: [C FAQ: Is char a[3] = "abc"; legal? What does it mean?](http://c-faq.com/ansi/nonstrings.html)

Comment: so because \0 does not get to end the character array, the string reduces to a character array.

Comment: @mrigendra The point is it's not a valid C string, so you can't use `%s` to print it in `printf`. Undefined behavior may result in anything.

Comment: so if  char arr[7]="hello my netowrk"; it would printf first 7 characters because its now a character array. But it shows error.

Comment: @mrigendra See the C FAQ article that I linked. Is that helpful?

Answer (score 3):

```
char str[7]="network";
```

This Invokes `Undefined behavior`.

You did not declared array with enough space

This should be

```
char str[8]="network";
```

Comment: No, the definition of `str` isn't undefined behavior, it's not a string, but valid `char` array.

Comment: Yeah, printing it invokes undefined behaviour

Comment: Definition also wrong. because OP wants to put 8 characters in the length of 7 characters array.because of less length than required , ignoring Null and making this invalid string. and then printing string which is not null terminated Invokes UB.

Comment: The undefined behavior happens when you try to print it as `%s`, assuming it's a string, not happens with the definition.

Comment: @YuHao Sorry , i am wrong about spelling That as UB.Definition is legal but wrong.that cannot be used as string and can be used as char array.

Answer (score 0):

```
char str[7]="network";
```

you did not provide enough space for the string

```
char str[8]="network";
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as what Gangadhar provided in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that stack pages start off completely zeroed in your system, so the string is actually null-terminated in memory, but not thanks to your code.

Try looking at the program in memory using a debugger, reading your platform documentation or printing out the contents of `str[7]` to get some clues. Doing so invokes undefined behavior but it's irrelevant when you're trying to figure out what your specific compiler and OS are doing at one given point in time.

Comment: tried it on turbo c in windows 7 and on gcc in ubuntu. i got the same answer. which debugger i can use for them

Comment: actually strcpy and strcmp works on it. its behaviour is like a string.

Comment: Again, it is completely reasonable for the OS to map zero pages for stack space. This means any byte you don't write to remains zeroed. Just fire up Visual Studio or GDB and take a look at the memory space right after your "string".